Is every set an image of a totally ordered set?
It is known that the statement "Every set admits a total order" is independent of ZF. See  here, for example. However, can it be proven in ZF that for every set $Y$, there exists a totally ordered set $X$ and a surjective map $X\to Y$?

It's definitely not provable in ZFA (since it's not provable there that "every linearly ordered set is well orderable" implies AC).

This is indeed not provable in ZF, but it's tricky to show. I'll add an answer when I have time later today if nobody else beats me to it coughAsafcough!

@Noah: I saw, I know what the answer is, but I am moving house today and everything is frantic. So by all means, take that one at your leisure... :)

While we await the knowledge drop from Noah, also note that this would imply the partition principle implies every set can be linearly ordered, which is open
